# Codename One refresh form

Tags: forms, refresh, codenameone, reload

In my app I want to reload a form. Problem is that every time I reload the form, existing items persists on the screen and new ones are added subsequently.

There are, for example, two buttons: buttonOne and buttonTwo. Both inside a container. The container is added to the form.

When I reload the form, buttonOne and buttonTwo are added again to the already existing two buttons. When I reload again, buttons One and Two are four times on the screen.

I have tried:

```
form.removeAll();
containerButton.removeAll();
containerButton.remove();
form.repaint();
form.refreshTheme();

// reload the form 

channels (); 

// the class

public Form form = new Form(new BoxLayout(2));

public void channels() { 

   container.add (buttonOne).add(buttonTwo);
   form.add (containerButton);

}
```

This approach does not solve the issue. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 3):

Remove all would remove the components from the `Container` (in this case the form content pane) but won't remove them through the hierarchy.

Both:

```
form.repaint();
form.refreshTheme();
```

Are incorrect API's to use when changing the hierarchy. You need to use `revalidate()` or `animateLayout()`.

"Reload" isn't a concept that exists in Codename One since the widgets are unaware of your data. A common fool proof trick is recreating the form from scratch and showing it.

Comment: related to reloading or recreateing the Form -- how can I make the widgets be aware of the changes in data? Is this possible? I am trying to clear a Form after submitting entered data to our server but the items still remain. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the way you created/loaded the form

Comment: Thank you @Shai Almog. I created the `Form` using a custom Constructor passing some values from a prior `Form`. To populate `TextArea`s, I pulled data from the db and populated a `MultiButton Spinner` initially from our backend, and then after the user selects an item, it will populate based on that selection that is saved in the db. Is there a way to clear all these items in a way that all items clear at once, or do I have to clear each one-by-one? I saw this answer you gave: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49993410/5095571 -- would that do the trick?

Comment: If you have them all in one container then a simple removeAll would work

Comment: Thanks; I realized that they're being populated to the db needed some adjustment and that seemed to solve this issue.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Perhaps a more comprehensive tutorial on how to use Properties style coding to create and populate the `Form` `Components` would be really useful. What do you think?

Comment: You can look for UIBinding in our website, there's already a tutorial